# Отличия ** от | в словарях Python

Tags: python, словари

есть такой код:

```
first = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
second = {'c': 3}
```

Нужно собрать два словаря в один результирующий. Обычно я делал это через `**`:

```
result = {**first, **second}
```

Но недавно наткнулся на такой вариант

```
result = first | second
```

Понимаю, что это оператор для объединения. Но какая разница между ними?
Что в одном случае `id` меняется, что в другом. Подскажите, может, есть ещё какие-то различия? Есть разница где что использовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160455/15035314 и https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/

Comment: Просто в питоне до 3.9 не было операции `|` для словарей, вот и приходилось изгаляться. Всё. )

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начну с `|`. Это оператор слияния `dict` с `dict` и был придуман для того, чтобы [решить проблему слияния двух списков](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/#abstract)

Грубо говоря, он просто создает новый словарь и добавляет 2 старых словаря, после чего *возвращает* новый словарь.

Просто и понятно. Рекомендую использовать его.

Для `**dict` ситуация другая. Грубо говоря, вы в конструктор просто передаете каждый элемент как (параметр = элемент), после чего заполняется `dict` и идет его возврат.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Непонятно, почему `операнд` и почему `списков`, если `оператор` и `словарей`

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо за уточнение. Перепутал понятия

Comment: А вот в `..., чтобы решить проблему слияния двух списков` - здесь действительно `списков`, а не `словарей`?

Answer (score 2):

До версии `Python 3.9` для объединения словарей использовался способ `{**first, **second}`, а способа `first | second` просто не существовало.

В версии `3.9` был введён способ `first | second` - как простой, красивый и интуитивно понятный. В том числе по мнению самого Гвидо Ван Россума, который посчитал старый способ не красивым и не интуитивным. В то же время способ `first | second` кажется более естественным для людей, знакомых, например, с объединением множеств в Питоне или знакомых вообще со знаком `|` как с "побитовым или" в Питоне, да и в других языках. Выглядит такой способ просто (без излишних символов) и интуитивно понятно. Поэтому он был добавлен в язык и с версии `3.9` лучше пользоваться этим способом, хотя старый способ, конечно, тоже работает.

Comment: Большое спасибо